# How can electric field be uniform in a conductor with charge separation when calculating the motional emf in it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, electric-current

We say the charges stop moving when $B×v=E$, but how we are saying it's uniform when we are considering that all the charges are at the ends (consider a rod for example)?

Conductor is straight and $B$ is uniform. And $v$ is uniform throughout conductor.

Comment: I am not fully understanding why you think it shouldn't be uniform.

Answer (score 1):

When I was first learning about motional emfs, and about the Hall effect, I had the same difficulty as you. I knew that there was a uniform electric field in the gap between the plates (with equal and opposite charges) of a parallel plate capacitor, *but only if the plate diameter or characteristic dimension is much greater than the gap*. But this condition (in italics) does not apply for a wire or a Hall wafer with charges piled up at its ends or on its 'side' faces.

The solution to the problem is in the equilibrium equation itself:$$\vec{E}=-\vec{v} \times \vec{B}.$$
This is the condition for there to be no net electromagnetic force on charge-carriers, and applies throughout the wire or Hall wafer. But $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{B}$ are constant throughout the wire or wafer, and therefore so is $\vec{E}$, when equilibrium has been reached, that is when charge carriers have migrated so that they produce an electric field that fits this equation at all points in the wire or wafer!

So don't worry about the configuration of charge carriers not being the same as in a parallel plate capacitor; there's more than one configuration that will give a uniform electric field!

Comment: How is this configuration achievable physically? I mean are the charges not at the ends ?